# Extra "count" row with total of 0

Tags: select, count

Consider the following:

```
db=> SELECT ga, count(ga) FROM gb GROUP BY ga ORDER BY ga ;
```

which gives the following output:

```
ga | count
---+------
?  |  200
A  |  100
B  |   50
   |    0
(4 rows)
```

Why is there an additional row with an empty `ga` and a count of zero?

Comment: Which database? Could it be a corruption in the index file? can you optimize the table, then rerun the query please? i.e. if MySQL, run 'OPTIMIZE TABLE gb;'. Not sure about other RDBMS, but you can try: `CREATE TABLE gb1 LIKE gb; INSERT INTO gb1 SELECT * FROM gb;` then try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is there an additional row with an empty ga and a count of zero?

Because there are `NULL` values in the `ga` column.

> Why the count is zero?

While `COUNT(*)` can never give 0 as a result (as it counts rows), `COUNT(column)` or `COUNT(expression)` can give 0 because it counts **not null** values in the column/expression.

Thus the only logical explanantion is that the `ga` column has some nulls.

> How many?

You can find out by running:

```
SELECT ga, 
       count(ga) AS count_non_nulls,
       count(*)  AS count_all
FROM gb 
GROUP BY ga 
ORDER BY ga ;
```

which will give you something like:

```
ga | count_non_nulls | count_all
---+-----------------+-----------
?  |  200            |  200
A  |  100            |  100
B  |   50            |   50
   |    0            |   17  -- some number >= 1 
(4 rows)
```